# Get Singleton of class that WILL be included

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, singleton

i currently have this classes:

`Activity`, `ActivityManager` (that extends `Activity`).

I have one method in `Activity`, that gets the singleton object of `ActivityManager`.

After a while, i saw that i got into a "live without life" paradox, as ActivityManager will only be "created" by the compiler, AFTER Activity is. So, how do i do this sort of stuff?

I mean, how can i get a class of an object that is extended from the first one?

I don't even know how to put this on google, so, help me please! Thanks

**EDIT**

Simplified `Activity`

```
class Activity
{
public:
    void start();
};

void Activity::start(void){
    // Start current Activity on the ActivityManager Stack
    ActivityManager *am;
    am = ActivityManager::getInstance();
    am->start(this);
}
```

Simplified `ActivityManager`:

```
class ActivityManager: public Activity
{
private:
    // Singleton Object
    static ActivityManager *singleton;

public:
    // Singleton method to return defauld object instance
    static ActivityManager* getInstance(void);

    // Overload method, used to run others Activityes
    void start(Activity& activity);

};

// Singleton method to return default ActivityManager object instance
ActivityManager* ActivityManager::getInstance(){
    if(!singleton) singleton = new ActivityManager();

    return singleton;
}

// Function called on request to start new activity
void ActivityManager::start(Activity& activity){
}
```

Comment: In what way are classes "created" by the compiler? You haven't explained your problem very well. Try showing us some code and any errors you  have.

Comment: Show some code please!

Comment: when i say "created", i mean "included"...

Comment: Why does it need to be a singleton? Seems like its making things complicated to think about. Just make one and pass it where it's needed.

Comment: @PeterWood Every Activity class will use the ActivityManager class, and ActivityManager MUST be extended from Activity class... Singleton is the best way, since i can only have ONE ActivityManager class instanced

Comment: The basic problem is that you want `ActivityMananager` to derive from `Activity`. I see no reason in your code or your explanation why that should be a requirement?

Comment: @Kleist ActivityManager will be the singleton object responsable for "mantaining" Activity objects. Every time, one Activity is starte, it will need to register itself, on ActivityManager singleton object

Comment: You gave some code that does not really have any problem compiling, what does not work ?

Comment: @IvanSeidel That doesn't really address Kleist's point. Why does ActivityManager have to derive from Activity. I mean besides "it just does."?

Comment: ActivityManager, is one normal "Activity" in my program... =]

Comment: @IvanSeidel again, what is not working ? :) all compiles fine (http://liveworkspace.org/code/1LV9y3$4)

Comment: @IvanSeidel: What prevents you from registering Activities in your ActivityManager if they are not related? Explain the dependency, or show some code that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Composite pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is better for your needs.

It would be some variation like this (naming is a bit screwed in terms of pattern, but they are more like your code this way):

```
class Activity
{
    public:
        virtual ~Activity();

        virtual void start();
        virtual void add(Activity*);
        virtual void remove(Activity*);

    private:
        Activity();
}



class ActivityManager : Activity
{
    public:
        ConcreteActivity();
        ~ConcreteActivity();

        void start();
        void add(Activity*);
        void remove(Activity*);

    private:
        list<Activity*> _activities;
}

void ActivityManager::start()
{
    list<Activity*>::const_iterator concreteActivity;

    for(concreteActivity = _activities.begin(), concreteActivity != _activities.end(); ++concreteActivity)
    {
        *concreteActivity->start();
    }
}

void ActivityManager::add(Activity* newActivity)
{
    _activities.push_back(newActivity);
}

void ActivityManager::remove(Activity* activityToDelete)
{
    _activities.remove(activityToDelete);
}




class SomeActivity : Activity
{
     public:
         SomeActivity();
         ~SomeActivity();

         void start();
}

class OtherActivity : Activity
{
     public:
         OtherActivity();
         ~OtherActivity();

         void start();
}
```

And the example of usage:

```
ActivityManager* manager = new ActivityManager();

SomeActivity* activity_one = new SomeActivity();
OtherActivity* activity_two = new OtherActivity();

manager->add(activity_one);
manager->add(activity_two);
manager->start();
```

And you still can make ActivityManager the Singleton, if you want. Without any additional info on your project, can't think of a better way.